# Accessing the content of the cells which are not on the screen causes fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview of more than 5 cells, however, there are only 5 appearing on the screen because of the height of the row. There is a button outside of the tableview, by tapping it, I want to access the content in each cell. Below is tap code,

```
@IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: Any) {

//array.count is bigger than the number of appearing cells on the screen.

    for i in 0..<array.count {
        let index = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: index) as! CustomTableViewCell
        for a in 0...6 {
            print(i)
            print(a)
            if let letter = cell.letter.text {
                print(letter)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once the button tapped, I got the error beside my code let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: index) as! CustomTableViewCell, Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The reason I think is because of the number of appearing cells on screen, if the array.count equals to or smaller than the number of cells which can be on the screen then there is no error.

I resized the height of cell and had x cells appearing on the screen, then if array.count > x, then it crashes, if equal or smaller than x, then it works.

I am not sure what the problem is, is it because of the reusable cell? How can I access the content in the cells not on the screen?

Comment: If a cell is not on screen, then `cellForRow(at:)` returns `nil`.  You shouldn't be accessing the cells directly anyway.  Get the data from your model.

Answer (score 1):

```
Modify your method:


@IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        //array.count is bigger than the number of appearing cells on the screen.

        for i in 0..<array.count {
            let index = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
            if let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell {
                for a in 0...6 {
                    print(i)
                    print(a)
                    if let letter = cell.letter.text {
                        print(letter)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @CraigLiu no problem